# Render index yii web framework

Tags: php, yii

Sorry i have a beginner question.
How to render index to be default page, for example i will render product page

Here this code,

Main.php

```
<a href="#" onclick="product()">prodct<a/>
```

SiteController.php

```
public function actionProduct(){
     $this->renderPartial('//site/product');
}
```

Script.js

```
function product(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=Site/product',
        success: function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It exactly work, But i use this same code to render index,

In SiteController.php must be $this-render('index'); and make the element is repeat

How can do?
pls explain and give code for me.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To set an action to be the default action in a `Controller`:

```
class MyController extends CController {

    public $defaultAction='product';

    // ... other code...
}
```